# Will (acid-free) paper turn yellow over time if I use tape (not acid-free) on it?

Tags: material-selection, paper, preservation

More context: I’ll stick the tape on the back, then the paper (lignin-free, acid-free cellulose, 120gsm) is painted on the front.

Comment: Hi Carlo, what exactly do you want to do? What's the tape on the back used for? Is it for hanging, or for keeping it in place as you work on it? Are you going to ground the paper before applying the paint?

Comment: Can you clarify the timeframe of "over time", and the type of tape?  The tape adhesive plays a big roll.  Over some period of time, some adhesives can bleed through and discolor the paper.  Many tape adhesives also have a life of a few years, so the tape could fail before the paper discolors, making the matter moot.  We'll need more specifics to be able to provide a useful answer.